# Jquery TypeError: $.template is not a function

Tags: jquery, html

I have run this sample and i am getting `TypeError: $.template is not a function`, and I could not able to solve this issue.

Can you please any one suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- To run the current sample code in your own environment, copy this to an html page. -->
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<html>
<head>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="result"></div>

<script id="theTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
<div>
   <em>Name:</em> {{:name}}
   {{if showNickname && nickname}}
      (Goes by <em>{{:nickname}}</em>)
   {{/if}}
</div>
</script>

<script>
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Robert",
    "nickname": "Bob",
    "showNickname": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Susan",
    "nickname": "Sue",
    "showNickname": false
  }
];
$(document).ready(function() {
var template = $.template("#theTmpl");

template.link("#result", data);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $.template means? any plugin?

Comment: You should include jQuery Template plugin (or whatever name it has) to the page to make it works.

Comment: I have followed this link, http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrplaying

Comment: and also i have tested by including this script <script src="http://www.jsviews.com/download/jsviews.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same problem, to me, downgrading solved it. There are two options:

1 - Downgrade wordpress to 4.4.2.
https://wordpress.org/wordpress-4.4.2.zip

how to:
step 1 - Replace all the files but wp-contend folder and wp-config.php.

step 2 - After you do this, it will ask for a database migration. Go ahead and accept it.

2 - Manually upgrade visual composer
You can also wait for the new release of visual composer, maybe it has reached the plugin network on the time you are reading this post.

Here is the link to the plugin version 4.11.2, compatible with wordpress 4.5
http://www.wdudes.com/wp-content/uploads/js_composer.zip

source: http://www.wdudes.com/fixed-visual-composer-not-working-updating-wordpress-4-5/

Answer (score -3):

`$.template` is part of the jsRender API, not jsViews (took 2 minutes looking at the resource you linked to find this out).

Include the correct script: http://www.jsviews.com/download/jsrender.min.js (from http://www.jsviews.com/#download)